# Linux mint no wifi connection

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I just switched today from windows to linux mint and can't figure out how connect to wifi. Driver manager is empty.

I have to do everything offline, tried few things but nothing worked, any ideas?
Motherboard: GA-B150M-D3H
Linuxmint 18

```
k@k-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M ~ $ lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:191f] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1458:5000]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1912] (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Skylake Integrated Graphics [1458:d000]
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
    Kernel modules: i915_bpo
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [1458:8888]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI [1458:1c3a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a102] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] [1458:b005]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a114] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a118] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a148] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [1458:5001]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H PMC [1458:5001]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [1458:a182]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H SMBus [1458:5001]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/333361/edit) by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GA-B150M-D3H motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5491) doesn't have onboard WiFi

Comment: Yep, figured out it already 20min ago, anyway thanks ;]